# Unhelpful review in "Help and Improvement" queue?

Tags: support

I was reviewing question / answers from the "Help and Improvement" queue, and suddenly I got this message:

> Your review on
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21652719 wasn't
>   helpful. Please do not approve/edit non-answers. These edits should be
>   declined and/or flagged as "not an answer".
>
> Come back on Dec 27 at 4:28 to continue reviewing.

Yet, if I look at the question (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21652719), I see:

```
Approved 30 mins ago:
Nic3500 reviewed this 30 mins ago: Edit
Community♦ reviewed this 30 mins ago: Approve
Ishara Madhawa reviewed this 44 mins ago: Approve
(less)


Reviewer Stats

Nic3500 has approved 1211 edit suggestions and rejected 706 edit suggestions and improved 97 edit suggestions
Community has approved 507838 edit suggestions and rejected 269627 edit suggestions and improved 4002 edit suggestions
Ishara Madhawa has approved 63 edit suggestions and rejected 2 edit suggestions and improved 14 edit suggestions
Editor Stats

Antu had 72 edit suggestions approved, and 20 edit suggestions rejected
```

My edit was to make the queries clearer.  From this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER {trigger_name} BEFORE INSERT ON {table_name} FOR EACH ROW SET new.{field_name} = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

To this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER {trigger_name} 
BEFORE INSERT ON {table_name} 
FOR EACH ROW SET new.{field_name} = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

It is a simple formatting edit, to avoid the long scrolling.  I do not do such edit just to get reputation points, I do not get those anymore.

If anyone has any idea on this, please let me know.  *Most of the time* I understand why reviewing is blocked, that one has me stumped.

---

**EDIT after the answer from Dany M.**

The review screen I had was this:

[image]

The "Thank you" sentence was already removed.  I did an edit to cut the long one liner.  I was not reviewing the answer with "Thank you", but the one on the right by Antu.  Hence why I think I was ok.

Comment: Re: your edit. You're in the suggested edits queue. You should be looking at both versions to make sure that the edit is acceptable. If you only look at the proposed version then you'll never know if it deviates from the authors intent or not.

Comment: Yep.  But as a reviewer, I look at if the edit is good or not right?  Here Antu removed the thank you sentence, and kept only the technical part of the answer, rendering it good.  Or so I thought.

Comment: The thank you was the evidence that it wasn't an answer, and the edit deviated from the original intent in that the original intent was to thank an existing answer, not copy their answer.

Comment: But shouldn't the fact the answer originally contained 'works like a charm, thank you' be a flag at some point in your review process? Yeah the edit made it 'ok' from that perspective.... But why was it in the answer in the first place? If you follow that train of thought, it's not long the truth rears its ugly head.

Comment: The answer should have been flagged as a non-answer, not end up in the edit review bin then.  From an editing standpoint, the edit was ok as it removed the offending content.

Comment: For sure someone should have sent that answer for deletion. But they didn't. And we don't polish turds in general on Stack. An edit should improve the post, sure. But it doesn't mean anything going that improved a post should be accepted as an edit

Comment: Adding to what Patrice said, in this case, Antu's edit was **not** an improvement. The original answer was Not An Answer, since it was simply thanking the accepted answer, but Antu's edit became **plagiarism** because with what Antu left over, it was a direct copy from the accepted answer without the attribution for the accepted answer included. Antu's edit made the answer worse, turning it from simply NAA to plagiarism, so it should have been rejected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue with this review isn't very obvious, so I'm not surprised you didn't catch it.

The code in that 'answer' is copied from the accepted answer. The clue at that something was wrong is that the original user wrote

> "WORKS LIKE A CHARM, Thank you very much for this. Created an account just to say thanks!"

Whenever you see someone posting something like this that sounds like they didn't intend to answer (A thank you at the end of an answer, or a follow up question), it's good to check the other answers to see if they're referencing someone.

In this case, it would have been correct to reject the suggested edit, then go and flag the original answer as not an answer (Or if it's not obvious like this one was, you might have wanted to mod-flag and explain that the code is copied from another answer).

---

Responding to your comment:

[image: The part of the review the OP Should have been looking at]

It's there. When reviewing edits, you need to read the original post to make sure the edit is good or not. It's what the editor removed that should have clued you in that this edit should have been rejected.

Comment: Please see my edit to the question.  I was not reviewing the "Thank you" answer, I was reviewing the one where it was already removed.

Comment: @Nic3500 I've updated my answer, but what I stated was still valid. I've used your same image and drawn a circle over what you should have considered during your review of Antu's edit.

Comment: Still, the new version is on the right is it not?  So Antu already removed this, keeping only the valid code.  Hence accepting Antu's edit is proper - well I thought so.

Comment: @Nic3500 You still need to judge the edit from the old to the new. Read the message on your ban: «Your review on https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21652719 wasn't helpful. Please do not approve/edit non-answers. These edits should be declined and/or flagged as "not an answer".» You should have declined the edit, not edit the edit to improve it to be on one line.